# Здесь главное : / — / , шляпа была бы цела

Tags: пунктуация

Как правильно?

> Здесь главное — шляпа была бы цела.

> Здесь главное, шляпа была бы цела.

> Здесь главное: шляпа была бы цела.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
О прерия, прерия, великая даль.
Индейские перья, английская сталь.
Тяжелая плата, смешная цена.
Тут главное — шляпа была бы цела.

Юлий Ким, песня  к фильму "Человек с бульвара Капуцинов"
```

*Тут главное — **шляпа была бы цела.***

**Пояснение**

БСП, отношения **изъяснительные**, обозначены **тире.** Для стихотворного текста в песенном варианте это наиболее **подходящий** знак.

**Двоеточие** предполагает наличие увеличенной **паузы** (интонационное предупреждение), а **запятой** недостаточно для обозначения **паузы** при изъяснительных отношениях.

Answer (score 0):

*Здесь главное* - вв. словос., указ. на связь мыслей, послед. излож.
Оно:

- не является чл. пр.;
- его можно переместить или убрать без потери смысла;
- к нему нельзя задать вопрос;
- можно заменить на "что важно".

Так как вв. сл. не явл. чл. пр., то оно обособляется: **","** или **"-"**.
Если во вв. сл. пропущено слово, то вместо одной зап. обычно ставится тире. (К п-ру,) **С одной стороны**, хотелось продолжать дорогу, **с другой -** чувствовалась потребность отдохнуть.

Т.к такого повода нет - ставится зап. [Источник](https://pishugramotno.ru/punktuacia/glavnoe-znaki-prepinaniya)

Comment: А почему вы  думаете, что это вводное слово? "Главное" может быть сказуемым. Вообще говоря, лучше обратиться к тексту и посмотреть решение там. А потом нужен грамматический анализ предложения. Откуда там сослагательное наклонение?  Точно ли оно простое, а не сложное? Отношения между частями предложения видятся как изъяснительные.

Comment: Я не к тому, чтобы критиковать вас. У  нас мало новых участников, мало отвечающих вообще. Нам нужны люди. Но будьте внимательны. В начале ответа приводите свой вариант записи. Обратите внимание, после "здесь" нет запятой. Почему?

Comment: Sharon, видимо, я опять ошибся (из-за сосл. накл. гл). Возможно, это СПП. И после **здесь** зап. не стоит из-за того, что это наречие. Тогда от сказуемого можно задать к нему вопрос: *главное (где?) здесь*.  Зап. бы нарушила эту связь. Что касается СПП, то уместен вопрос от глав. ч. *(здесь главное)* к придаточной . Так? Имею ввиду, вопрос **(главное) что?** Что *(шляпа была бы цела)*

Comment: Рустам, люди такие разные) Пока наши мыслительные пространства  не пересекаются, но как знать) Так, я не задаю вопросы без особой надобности. Вижу по семантике, что отношения изъяснительные, но это БСП. Сослагательное наклонение задает желательность действия (чтобы была цела). В БСП возможен любой их трех знаков, поэтому автор просит помочь его выбрать. Попробуйте это сделать.

Comment: *...словос., указ. на связь мыслей, послед. излож.* И тир. сокр. до деф. . //// Искл. по форме зап.: эконом. св. время. засч. других. — где так учат?